# jQuery .find('img') Error Unrecognized Expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, rss, google-feed-api

I am taking information from Google's Feed API and finding trying to find an image from each entry. When I do so it will be success until it hits a something like facebook or twitter (I'm not really sure what breaks it, either only facebook or twitter or entries without images).

The error Chrome gives me is: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: *entry content here*`

part of that entry is: https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=821283904584218&set=vb.246699672042647&type=2&theater

Here is my success function if the Google Feed API loads the RSS feed.

```
.success(function(data) {
     $scope.rssTitle = data.responseData.feed.title;
     $scope.rssUrl = data.responseData.feed.feedUrl;
     $scope.rssSiteUrl = data.responseData.feed.link;
     $scope.entries = data.responseData.feed.entries;

     var data = data.responseData.feed;

     var findFirstImage = data.entries.content;
     angular.forEach(data.entries, function(value) {
       value.sampleImage = $(value.content).find('img').eq(0).attr('src');
     })
})
```

Comment: Did add `console.lines` to see what all the values are?

Comment: @charlietfl It's a code snippet I found. Is there a better way about finding and extracting images from an entry?

Comment: @charlietfl the information from data.entries is a string with some  HTML in it. I am trying to extract the image from the entry and pass it to the view where an ng-repeat loops through and adds a title and image for each entry.